# super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type Django

Tags: django, ajax

I work on a small Django App and get an error tells me: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type.I am trying to save the details of the sale in the database but I get this error.

[image: ErrorPic]

Views

```
class VentaCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, ValidatePermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Venta
    form_class = nueva_venta_form
    template_name = 'venta/venta_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Index')
    permission_required = 'store_project_app.change_categoria'
    url_redirect = success_url

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']
            if action == 'autocomplete':
    
            elif action == 'add':
                #ventas = request.POST['action']
                #ventas = request.POST['ventas']
                ventas = json.loads(request.POST['ventas'])
                #print(ventas)
                venta = Venta()
                venta.id_cliente = Cliente.objects.get(id_cliente = ventas['id_cliente'])
                venta.id_empleado = Empleado.objects.get(id_empleado = ventas['id_empleado'])
                venta.fecha_venta = ventas['fecha_venta']
                venta.forma_pago = Metodo_Pago.objects.get(id_metodo_pago = ventas['forma_pago'])
                venta.precio_total = float(ventas['precio_total'])
                venta.save()

                for i in ventas['productos']:
                     detalle_venta = Detalle_Venta()
                     detalle_venta.id_venta = venta.id_venta
                     detalle_venta.id_producto = i['id_producto']
                     detalle_venta.cantidad = int(i['cantidad'])
                     detalle_venta.subtotal = float(i['subtotal'])
                     detalle_venta.save()
            else:
                data['error'] = 'No ha ingresado a ninguna opción'
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Crear una Venta'
        context['entity'] = 'Venta'
        context['list_url'] = self.success_url
        context['action'] = 'add'
        return context
```

Comment: That's a really broad `try`. Can you include a stacktrace to show what the code is doing & what line causes the error?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: It'd also be good to include your javascript. Given that `message_error` is causing an failure in that as well. This may help; https://code-maven.com/python-print-stack-trace-after-catching-exception

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was much easier to track my mistake, I could already fix it.